# Error 522 with Cloudflare and Google Cloud Platform

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, cloudflare, connection-timeout

I am new with google cloud platform and Cloudflare CDN. I am getting the "Error 522" connection timed out error. I contacted the Google Cloud Platform. They told me, No errors on their end. I also contacted the Cloudflare support. Here's what they gave me:

1. Make sure that you're not blocking Cloudflare IPs in .htaccess, iptables or your firewall.
2. Make sure your hosting provider isn't rate limiting or blocking IP requests from the Cloudflare IPs and ask them to whitelist the IP addresses here: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips.

**Now My Questions are:**

1. How can I check Google Cloud Platform is not blocked Cloudflare IPs?
2. How can I check Google Cloud Platform isn't rate limiting or blocking IP requests from the Cloudflare IPs.
3. How to whitelist the IP addresses of Cloudflare.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Which Google Cloud Platform product you're using (i.e. Google App Engine, Cloud DNS, Cloud Armor...)?

Comment: You can check firewall rules to verify if its not blocking Cloudflare IPs. Also, I have [this](https://judge.sh/firewalling-cloudflare-with-google-cloud-platform/) article to show which firewall rule you need to allow for Cloudflare IPs. You can also check in [Stackdriver logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview) if you see your requests are failing. Last, are you trying naked domain (i.e. are you trying example.com or www.example.com), what are the results for trying both?